# while removing element tag from the html clone using jquery getting an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Getting an html div on the basis of id and making the clone of it and trying to remove particular css class getting following error.

> ERROR: Invalid source - please specify an HTML Element or string.

```js
document.getElementById("btnPrint").onclick = function() {
  var cont = $('#element-to-print').clone(); // clone of html div
  var newt = $(cont).find(".masteredit").remove(); // trying to remove the particular css class from clone.
  html2pdf(newt, { // sending clone(newt) to print
    margin: 0.25,
    filename: $scope.defendantHeader.firstName + "-" + $scope.defendantHeader.lastName + "-" + $scope.defendantHeader.activeFileNumber,
    image: {
      type: 'jpeg',
      quality: 0.98
    },
    html2canvas: {
      dpi: 192,
      letterRendering: true
    },
    jsPDF: {
      unit: 'in',
      format: 'letter',
      orientation: 'portrait'
    },
    });
  }))
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your code in the question. This was completely unreadable before I edited it

Comment: What happens when you try and output the result of the find method in the console instead of using remove()?

Comment: Invalid source - please specify an HTML Element or string.                          getting this error in console.

Comment: The remove will return you the .masteredit object - if it exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you're providing the `html2pdf()` constructor with a jQuery object, when it expects a string or Element object (as per the [documentation](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf/blob/master/README.md)).

Note that you're using the outdated `onclick` property when you should be using an unobtrusive event handler. Also, you're rebuilding the `cont` object again, which can be avoided. Try this instead:

```
$(function() {
  $('#btnPrint').click(function() {
    var $cont = $('#element-to-print').clone();
    $cont.find(".masteredit").remove();

    html2pdf($cont[0], { 
      margin: 0.25,
      filename: $scope.defendantHeader.firstName + "-" + $scope.defendantHeader.lastName + "-" + $scope.defendantHeader.activeFileNumber,
      image: {
        type: 'jpeg',
        quality: 0.98
      },
      html2canvas: {
        dpi: 192,
        letterRendering: true
      },
      jsPDF: {
        unit: 'in',
        format: 'letter',
        orientation: 'portrait'
      },
    });
  }))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.remove()` function removes the whole html element. use `.css()` function or `removeClass()` for removing css related issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try `var newt = $(cont).removeClass("masteredit");` instead

Comment: var cont = $('#element-to-print').clone();
  var newt = $(cont).removeClass("masteredit"); // not working                    error : Invalid source - please specify an HTML Element or string.